# NodeJS environment variables in Grunt

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, gruntjs

I'm shifting my project from simply `node server.js` into using Grunt.

I used to run my application directly from webstorm, and environment variables would be set up for me.

How can I achieve the same in Grunt?

I need to either run grunt from webstorm (windows), or set up env vars when running grunt (explicitly)

This isn't an issue when deploying because heroku already takes care of setting my env vars.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

use the grunt-env plugin: https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-env

and set your config:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  env : {
    options : {
      //Shared Options Hash
    },
    dev : {
      NODE_ENV : 'development',
      DEST     : 'temp'
    }
  },
  'another-task': {}
});
```

in your gruntfile you will probably define some default-task:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['env', 'another-task']);
```

so if you run 'grunt default' at first your env-vars are set, and then 'another-task' is run

if you want to specify the current environment via command-line option you could use grunt.option:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  env : {
    options : {
      //Shared Options Hash
    },
    dev : {
      NODE_ENV : grunt.option('environment') || 'development',
      DEST     : 'temp'
    }
  },
```

in this example if you call your grunt task with `--environment=production` production will be set, otherwise development will be set

Comment: If you ever need to get access to env variable in your js app (like Ember) you can use that pattern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742882/how-set-get-environment-specific-variable-in-a-yeoman-ember-app/20974746#20974746

Comment: Upvoted too soon and realized too late to downvote properly. Does not work in Windows (cmd or ps).

Comment: the library extends process.env with your config data. im not familiar with node.js on windows, but i don't see any reason why it shouldn't work...

Comment: You also need to add `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-env');`

Comment: How do you use with a JSON file as it describes in docs? My key.json file has `{ "KEY": "VALUE"}` and I have `env.dev.src` set to key.json, but when I try to use process.env.key in my code, it comes back undefined. Does the file need to be in a certain order?

Comment: I have configured it to read env variables from a .env file but I cannot seem to be able to read them in my file. Any ideas on how to do that? Thanks!