# Handling environment-specific configuration in a javascript app

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman

*Context : a single-page backbone application build with yeoman*

I would like a way to have some application parameters depend on my current environment (dev vs production).

Right now I am using two separate config files, and I switch the dev one to the prod one when deploying which the grunt:usemin task :

```
// index.html
<!-- build:js scripts/config.prod.js -->
<script src="scripts/config.dev.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->    

// config.dev.js
window.config = {
    api_host: 'localhost:9393',
    api_key:  'dev_api_key'
}

// config.prod.js
window.config = {
    api_host = 'api.host.tld',
    api_key =  'prod_api_key'
}
```

This solution works but is smelly and doesn't allow any other environment than production and dev. What are my alternatives?

Comment: You could try to preprocess your HTML file and replace an placeholder

Comment: possible duplicate of [NodeJS environment variables in Grunt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554215/nodejs-environment-variables-in-grunt)

Comment: Here one detailed answer for Yeoman: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742882/how-set-get-environment-specific-variable-in-a-yeoman-ember-app/20974746#20974746

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var DEV = (window.location.indexOf("DEV=1")) != -1 ? true : false;
```

Then type `?DEV=1` after your URL.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [grunt-variablize](https://github.com/msn0/grunt-variablize) task.